# What date of next Friday?

Tags: php, date

I need to know the date of next Friday. Known only today's date.
PHP / Framework Laravel 5.1
How do I know the date of the next Friday?
Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: `$nextFriday = new DateTime('this friday');`, or `next friday` depending on requirements.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that `next friday` will actually give you the **next** Friday (so the 28th from today) and **not** Friday week (`friday +1 week`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nice and easy using `strtotime`

```
strtotime('next friday');
```

See [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: Looks like I should have checked the comments before posting this answer